# Integrating hstore column with simple_form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, hstore

Is there a good way to integrate `hstore` with `simple_form`?

I just cannot find a way to achieve this. I have a column called `widget_locations` and I would like to store `:left_area1, :mid_area1, :left_area2, :mid_area2, :right_area2` as keys and values as nested hashes so they are like below:

```
{:left_area1 => {:video_id => 1, :presentation_id => 3}, :mid_area1 => {:chat_id => 1, :presentation_id => 5}, :left_area2, :mid_area2, :right_area2}
```

Is there a best way to achieve this in simple_form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :widget_locations do |location| %>
    <%= location.input :left_area1, :input_html => { :value => <value> } %>
    <%= location.input :mid_area1, :input_html => { :value => <value> } %>
<% end %>
```